# How to solve problem with OpenCV in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv

I have a following problem with OpenCV (cv2). I dont know how to solve it. 
I am using VS 2019, the latest OpenCV and the latest Python Environment

Error code:
OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:627: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

```
'''
    Copyright 2017 by Satya Mallick ( Big Vision LLC )
    http://www.learnopencv.com
'''

import cv2
import numpy as np


def fillHoles(mask):
    '''
        This hole filling algorithm is decribed in this post
        https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/
    '''
    maskFloodfill = mask.copy()
    h, w = maskFloodfill.shape[:2]
    maskTemp = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
    cv2.floodFill(maskFloodfill, maskTemp, (0, 0), 255)
    mask2 = cv2.bitwise_not(maskFloodfill)
    return mask2 | mask

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read image
    img = cv2.imread("red_eyes.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Output image
    imgOut = img.copy()

    # Load HAAR cascade
    eyesCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_eye.xml")

    # Detect eyes
    eyes = eyesCascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=4, minSize=(100, 100))

    # For every detected eye
    for (x, y, w, h) in eyes:

        # Extract eye from the image
        eye = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        # Split eye image into 3 channels
        b = eye[:, :, 0]
        g = eye[:, :, 1]
        r = eye[:, :, 2]

        # Add the green and blue channels.
        bg = cv2.add(b, g)

        # Simple red eye detector.
        mask = (r > 150) &  (r > bg)

        # Convert the mask to uint8 format.
        mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)*255

        # Clean mask -- 1) File holes 2) Dilate (expand) mask.
        mask = fillHoles(mask)
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, anchor=(-1, -1), iterations=3, borderType=1, borderValue=1)

        # Calculate the mean channel by averaging
        # the green and blue channels
        mean = bg / 2
        mask = mask.astype(np.bool)[:, :, np.newaxis]
        mean = mean[:, :, np.newaxis]

        # Copy the eye from the original image.
        eyeOut = eye.copy()

        # Copy the mean image to the output image.
        #np.copyto(eyeOut, mean, where=mask)
        eyeOut = np.where(mask, mean, eyeOut)

        # Copy the fixed eye to the output image.
        imgOut[y:y+h, x:x+w, :] = eyeOut

    # Display Result
    cv2.imshow('Red Eyes', img)
    cv2.imshow('Red Eyes Removed', imgOut)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Error above, I menotied on the photo

Comment: [Why not upload images of code when posting on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica How to properly explain this error?

Comment: I am sitting in front of the computer for 4h and still this error occurs

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a [mcve] as text along with the text of the error message (again, as text)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica now is correctly?

Comment: Can you include what code you were trying too?

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/ I tried to install it from this site

Comment: error occurs at cv2.imshow()

Comment: Thanks, the edits help a lot.

Comment: Did you explicitly disable `WITH_WIN32UI`? Because that's on by default when building on windows. In all the times I've built OpenCV with Visual Studio, I've never had to do anything at all to get the windows HighGUI backend. I'd suggest having another go, and thoroughly documenting all the steps, and post that as a new question. The problem is in how you build OpenCV, the code example you posted here won't help figure that out.

Comment: Roger that. If I will not solve my problem I will post another post. Thanks guys